# How to protect and access nested objects in multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, delphi, critical-section, delphi-xe8

I have an object with nested objects. Simple diagram of object organziation would be:

```
TMainObj
-TState
-TDescriptor
-List<TSubObj>
--TSubObj_n
---TSubObjState
---TSubObjDesc
---TSubObjData

type TState = class
end;

type TDesc = class
end;

type TSubObjState = class
end;

type TSubObjDesc = class
end;

type TSubObjData = class
end;

type TSubObj = class
  FSubObjState: TSubObjState;
  FSubObjDesc: TSubObjDesc;
  FSubObjData: TSubObjData;
end;

type TListSubObj = class (TList<TSubObj>)
end;

type TMainObj = class
  FState: TState;
  FDesc: TDesc;
  FList: TList<TSubObj>
end;
```

I have multithreaded app and I have to enable access to objects and their properties (which are not included in this example code). Some threads share same objects some not but still they could share some properties with main thread therfore I need to protect data. I am protecting data with critical sections / mutexes. However I don't know how to organize locking mechanism in this scheme to get the best out of it.

My initial idea was to implement lock/unlock on TMainObj and whenever any thread needs to access any property or subobjects it will lock complete TMainObj and all other threads will need to wait until TMainObj becomes unlocked. For that reason I think this not really good idea. Some threads doesn't need to access TMainObj's properties but only it's sub object such as TState. I assume there is no need to lock whole TMainObj but only TState or am I missing something?

If I need to access properties on TMainObj I would do it:

```
TMainObj.Lock
try
  TMainObj.Name := 'Just name!';
  TManiObj.Id   := 1;
finally
  TMainObj.Unlock;
end;
```

And every other thread will have to wait to gain an access.

But what when I need to access sub class TDescriptor? I can do it like that:

```
TMainObj.Lock
try
  TMainObj.Descriptor.DataLen := 1024;
  TManiObj.Descriptor.Count   := 10;
finally
  TMainObj.Unlock;
end;
```

And complete TMainObj will be locked. And all other threads need to wait even if they are not 'interested' in changing TMainObj's properties.

Or that way to lock only sub object descriptor:

```
Thread1:
    TMainObj.Descriptor.Lock
    try
      TMainObj.Descriptor.DataLen := 1024;
      TManiObj.Descriptor.Count   := 10;
    finally
      TMainObj.Descriptor.Unlock;
    end;
```

Meanwhile some other thread can still access TMainObj properties and change them, right?

```
Thread2: 
    TMainObj.Lock;
    try
      TMainObj.Name := 'New name!';
    finally
      TMainObj.Unlock;
    end;
```

Here is the image which shows how and what each thread is accessing. [image: Threads accessing one object with subobjects]

One of concerns is a deadlock situation. In next case I would like to show how different threads are accessing different "part" of MainObj.

MainThread:

```
MainObj.Lock;
try
  MainObj.Name = 'Different name!'
  MainObj.Id   = 2;
finally
MainObj.Unlock;
end;
```

Meanwhile thread1 is doing this:

```
MainObj.Descriptor.Lock;
try
   MainObj.Descriptor.DataLen = 1024;
   MainObj.Descriptor.Count   = 1;
finally
  MainObj.Descriptor.Unlock;
end;
```

So both are sharing MainObj but each is changing own part of object. Is that approach of locking appropriate?

I hope I explained my problem as clear as possible. My question is how to protect access to such object structure from different threads? Do I have to protect each subobject with it's own lock/unlock pair methods (and critical section)?

Comment: MainThread is working with TMainObject and it's properties and subobjects (TState, TDescription). I have additional threads. One is working only with TState and another only with TDescription.  So each thread is sharing something with mainthread. So when Main thread is changing only properties on MainObject the lock must lock out only those properties while some other thread can still  change TState or TDescriptor objects. My question is if this is ok that I lock only some parts of object or should I lock complete object?

Comment: Pretty hard to advise you without the full picture, in my view

Comment: Please add a tag with your Delphi version - available threading code varies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TMonitor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TMonitor) for this without adding anything to your objects. In that case your code would look like this:

```
TMonitor.Enter(MainObj.Descriptor);
try
  MainObj.Descriptor.DataLen := 1024;
  MainObj.Descriptor.Count   := 10;
finally
  TMonitor.Exit(MainObj.Descriptor);
end;
```

Provided all threads (and the main thread) that are trying to access descriptor do the same thing then they will lock waiting for the next thread to finish.

You will need to watch out for deadlocks but from what you say it shouldn't be a problem. A deadlock will occur if you do something like this:

```
Main Thread
  Lock MainObj
  Lock MainObj.Descriptor (waits for thread 1)
```

If thread 1 comes along and does this:

```
Thread 1
  Lock MainObj.Descriptor
  Lock MainObj (waits for main thread)
```

Comment: That exactly was my concern. A deadlock situation when having a nested objects. First I need to figure out if there will be any scenario in my case which could lead to such deadlock.  I read a post by Eric Grange comparing TCriticalSection and TMonitor and his conclusion was not to use TMonitor if performance matters so I thought using TCriticalSection is better option.

Comment: There have been some improvements to TMonitor in terms of performance. Read the comments in Eric's blog.

Comment: On Windows I think you'd have to be verging on insane no to use the native in process lock, the critical section. TMonitor has had a pretty poor record.